artefact using geom_sf() in ggplot
I am trying to create a flow map where the arrows go from one realm to another (e.g., Figure
To this, I have this data. Please note that this is a small subset of the data for replicability.
    structure(list(Realm_native = c("neartic", "neartic", "paleartic", 
"australasia", "neartic"), Realm_invaded = c("indomalayan", "australasia", 
"neartic", "neartic", "neotropic"), count = c(7L, 9L, 31L, 10L, 
20L), native_x = c(-100.61622017873, -100.61622017873, 61.0008389149679, 
135.89521667746, -100.61622017873), native_y = c(52.2161961861738, 
52.2161961861738, 53.0763354935295, -23.5028012498415, 52.2161961861738
), invaded_x = c(95.1816835711229, 135.89521667746, -100.61622017873, 
-100.61622017873, -62.8078522666971), invaded_y = c(18.235516960872, 
-23.5028012498415, 52.2161961861738, 52.2161961861738, -11.4781140762962
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

However, my result is a bit messy, for instance, the lines from North America to Australia. 
The code I am using is: (using robin projection)
 realm_movements3 <- realm_movements3 %>%
    mutate(
      geometry_native = st_transform(geometry_native, crs = "+proj=robin"),
      curved_geometry = st_transform(curved_geometry, crs = "+proj=robin") )
ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = realm_movements3, aes(geometry = geometry_native, fill = Realm_native), color = NA) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = realm_colors) +
    theme_minimal() +
    geom_sf(
      data = realm_movements3,
      aes(geometry = curved_geometry, color = Realm_native, linewidth = count),  # No alpha in aes()
      arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")),
      alpha = 0.5  # Set alpha globally
    ) +
    scale_color_manual(values = realm_colors2)+
    scale_size_continuous(
      range = c(0.5, 3),  
      name = "Arrow Thickness") +
    guides(
      color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 3)) ) +
    theme(
      legend.position = "none",
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
      panel.grid = element_line(color = "gray90", linetype = "dashed"),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x = element_blank(),  # Remove x-axis numbers
      axis.text.y = element_blank()   # Remove y-axis numbers
    )

